# How to take mean of 3 values before flag change 0 to 1python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with columns `A`,`B` and `flag`. I want to calculate mean of 2 values before flag change from 0 to 1 , and record value when flag change from 0 to 1 and record value when flag changes from 1 to 0.

```
# Input dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]})

# Expected output
df_out=df=pd.DataFrame({'A_mean_before_flag_change':[5.5],
                        'B_mean_before_flag_change':[5],
                        'A_value_before_change_flag':[7], 
                        'B_value_before_change_flag':[6]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to create more general solution:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]})
print (df)
     A   B  flag
0    1   1     0
1    3   3     0
2    4   4     0
3    7   6     0
4    8   8     1
5   11  11     1
6    1   1     1
7   15  19     0
8   20  20     0
9   15  15     1
10  16  16     0
11  87  87     1
```

First create groups by mask for `0` with next `1` values of `flag`:

```
m1 = df['flag'].eq(0) & df['flag'].shift(-1).eq(1)
df['g'] = m1.iloc[::-1].cumsum()
print (df)
     A   B  flag  g
0    1   1     0  3
1    3   3     0  3
2    4   4     0  3
3    7   6     0  3
4    8   8     1  2
5   11  11     1  2
6    1   1     1  2
7   15  19     0  2
8   20  20     0  2
9   15  15     1  1
10  16  16     0  1
11  87  87     1  0
```

then filter out groups with size less like `N`:

```
N = 4    
df1 = df[df['g'].map(df['g'].value_counts()).ge(N)].copy()
print (df1)
    A   B  flag  g
0   1   1     0  3
1   3   3     0  3
2   4   4     0  3
3   7   6     0  3
4   8   8     1  2
5  11  11     1  2
6   1   1     1  2
7  15  19     0  2
8  20  20     0  2
```

Filter last `N` rows:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('g').tail(N)
```

And aggregate `last` with `mean`:

```
d = {'mean':'_mean_before_flag_change', 'last': '_value_before_change_flag'}
df3 = df2.groupby('g')['A','B'].agg(['mean','last']).sort_index(axis=1, level=1).rename(columns=d)
df3.columns = df3.columns.map(''.join)
print (df3)
   A_value_before_change_flag  B_value_before_change_flag  \
g                                                           
2                          20                          20   
3                           7                           6   

   A_mean_before_flag_change  B_mean_before_flag_change  
g                                                        
2                      11.75                      12.75  
3                       3.75                       3.50
```

Comment: this solution is ok for shift mask for 2 rows before, if shift mask for 8 rows before need , which part need to change ?

Comment: @Edward - Unfortunately all solution. Please give me some time.

Comment: @Edward - Is no problem if overlaping groups? Like if in sample data in my answer `N= 8` then are last groups overlaps. Or in real data it is not possible?

Comment: in ideal condition overlaping is not  allowed

Comment: @Edward - So need solution for ideal data, it means no groups overlapping?

Comment: Yes,  but for reference i want to tell you in real data when rising edge will come before this 8 points will available for mean , in your test data before last group only 1 point but in real data there will be points more than 8 and i only need to take mean of 8 points

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this needs to work for cases with more than one rising edge and that the consecutive values and averages get appended to the output lists:

```
# the first step is to extract the rising and falling edges using diff(), identify sections and length
df['flag_diff'] = df.flag.diff().fillna(0)
df['flag_sections'] = (df.flag_diff != 0).cumsum()
df['flag_sum'] = df.flag.groupby(df.flag_sections).transform('sum')

# then you can get the relevant indices by checking for the rising edges
rising_edges = df.index[df.flag_diff==1.0]
val_indices = [i-1 for i in rising_edges]
avg_indices = [(i-2,i-1) for i in rising_edges]

# and finally iterate over the relevant sections
df_out = pd.DataFrame()
df_out['A_mean_before_flag_change'] = [df.A.loc[tpl[0]:tpl[1]].mean() for tpl in avg_indices]
df_out['B_mean_before_flag_change'] = [df.B.loc[tpl[0]:tpl[1]].mean() for tpl in avg_indices]
df_out['A_value_before_change_flag'] = [df.A.loc[idx] for idx in val_indices]
df_out['B_value_before_change_flag'] = [df.B.loc[idx] for idx in val_indices]
df_out['length'] = [df.flag_sum.loc[idx] for idx in rising_edges]
df_out.index = rising_edges
```

Comment: everytime when rising edge occured result should have one row in dataframe

Comment: In that case just add the list responses to the dataframe. If you need the indices of the rising edges (to be able to easily associate the results to the correct edge), you'll need to copy these to the resulting dataframe as well (see edit).

Comment: other things seems well now , there is one problem , i also need to record length of each rising edge , you can add this one ?

Comment: edited to include the length of the sections after the rising edges